# Удалить часть строки preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка https://site.com/ru/moskov/medceter&page=2
Еще бывает  https://site.com/ru/moskov/medceter?page=2

Нужно убрать &page=2 либо же ?page=2
Пробовал так

```
preg_replace('/page=[0-9]+&?/','',$href);
```

Но не убирается спец символы ? и &...

Answer (score 1):

Вот так?

```
preg_replace('#(&|\?|&amp;)page=[0-9]+#','',$href);
```

Comment: Если строка будет `https://site.com/ru/moskov/medceter?page=2&some=true`, в результате получится `https://site.com/ru/moskov/medceter&some=true`. По-моему, в результает должно быть `https://site.com/ru/moskov/medceter?some=true`.

Comment: Не убирает &page=, а если  preg_replace('#[&amp;?]page=[0-9]+#','',$href) , то не убирает амперсанд &

Comment: @ДенисЛинник, а так?

Comment: так ошибка  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 3

Answer (score 0):

Помогло следующее:

```php
preg_replace('((\?|&amp;|&)page=[0-9]+)','',$href)
```

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/[?&]page=\d+/', '', $href);`